# What are the career implications of choosing a non-accredited postgraduate degree?

Tags: materials, education, licensure

I am looking to complete a materials science/engineering-based Master's degree in the UK. Those which I have been looking at, particularly Leeds and Manchester, do not seem to be accredited by the [IOM3](http://www.iom3.org/) or other institutions.

I am interested in becoming chartered/incorporated in the future. If I were to complete an unaccredited course, what impact would the lack of accreditation have on my career prospects in the field of materials science/engineering?

Comment: I'm not sure about UK - I know USA's options.  Take a look at [NCEES](http://ncees.org/credentials-evaluations/) - they state that your degree should be EAC accredited from ABET.  None of that matches what you have written, so it may not matter in your situation, but it is useful to look over [the basic requirements](http://ncees.org/credentials-evaluations/ncees-engineering-education-standard/) listed by NCEES - this list details the 96 credit hours they look for when considering someone's requirements.

Comment: Please note that [we do not offer individual academic guidance](http://meta.engineering.stackexchange.com/q/261/368). We may be able to give some information about accreditation as it relates to your field but this may be a difficult question to answer.

Comment: @Mark What little I know about the UK Chartered Engineer process leads me to believe that any comparisons to the Professional Engineer process in the US won't be useful.

Comment: @hazzey - I figured as much, but figured my comment might help the *People of the Future* who find this in search.

Comment: I didn't intend this to be a question of individual guidance. More in general i.e. is it likely that further study would be required etc. Rather than my asking 'should I do the course?' - if this makes a difference.

Comment: I would say there is a difference, but I still don't think the Q&A format used at Stack Exchange can help out to much in either kind of question.  I'd say that I would *assume additional study will be required* until you can talk to a counselor at your school to be assured that it will not.

Comment: @Phizzy, Did you obtain your first degree from a accredited institution?

Comment: I did yes - but I don't plan on returning there!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try asking the [IOM3](http://www.iom3.org/) & other accrediting institutions why the courses you are interested in are not accredited and if there is a possibility that they could be accredited in the near future.

The courses may not cover material that such institutions consider vital for professionals engaged in that field and which would be required for membership of the institutions.

If you were to study one of those courses you may need to study the missing subjects elsewhere prior to being eligible to for membership of the institutions.

Regarding employment prospects, it's safer to study an accredited course. In times of economic downturns or gluts of professionals in particular fields employers can be very discriminating. Anyone without an accredited qualification can more easily have their application disregarded.

It's not just job prospects in the UK that you need to consider; materials science/engineering is an international profession. Larger companies track the performance of universities and the courses they offer and they know which universities offer courses that are of most interest to them.

Companies also prefer to employ people with accredited qualifications so as to minimize any legal issues should there be a problem arising from their products or services and the personnel responsible for those products or services did not have an accredited qualification.